# Qual o limite de armazenamento do SQLite?

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, sqlite

Surgiu uma nova demanda para o aplicativo da empresa onde trabalho, preciso armazenar mais de 100k de registros em tabelas diferentes, estou preocupado se o SQLite vai aguentar tal demanda, minha dúvida é:

- O SQLite possui limite de armazenamento?
- O tipo de dado influência no armazenamento limite?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

O limite de linhas é 2 elevado a 64, ou seja, não há um limite prático.

Há o limite de 128TB no tamanho total de *bytes* do banco de dados, o que na prática é difícil alcançar. Lembrando que o SQLite trabalha com todo banco de dados em um único arquivo.

Claro que este limite depende de configuração do SQLite, seja na compilação dele, seja por algum `PRAGMA`, então é possível mudar.

Quase todos os limites do banco de dados podem ser configurados e os relevantes estão disponíveis na [documentação](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html).

O tamanho das páginas pode afetar positiva ou negativamente a performance do banco de dados. Em geral os melhores resultados são obtidos entre 8K e 32K, o que limitaria um pouco mais o tamanho se estiver querendo o máximo desempenho (mas muda pouco e depende do cenário).

O maior problema de escalabilidade do SQLite se dá quando precisa uma quantidade muito grande de escritas concorrentes. Como o travamento dele não tem granularidade, qualquer tentativa de gravação impede outras escritas mesmo em pontos que não estão em concorrência. Não afeta a leitura, a menos que não esteja usando o WAL, que é recomendado em quase todas situações.

O tipo de dado não influencia no limite, apenas no tamanho ocupado. Claro que cada tipo tem seu próprio limite.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Lendo novamente minha pergunta, talvez hoje eu nem fizesse essa pergunta...hahaha, acredito que hoje seja muito mais viável usar apis rest e usar o front como a casca do app..SQLite serviria apenas para coisas simples. Muito bom!